# How do I clean up this ugly piece of code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

I picked up a project mid-way, and have this kind of constructors all over the place: I'm talking in particular about all these this.x = this.x.bind(this) and the column definitions.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

const routerstate = props.router.location.state || {};
const { query } = props.router.location;
const tabs = this.defineTabs();
this.state = {
  tabs: tabs,
  activeTab: routerstate.activeTab ? tabs.get(routerstate.activeTab) : tabs.get(1),
  complaints: null,
  selectedComplaint: null,
  nrselected: 0,
  showSearch: false,
  sortModel: { colId: query.sortBy || 'createdDate', sort: query.sortDirection || "desc" }
};

this.changeTab = this.changeTab.bind(this);
this.showComplaintDetail = this.showComplaintDetail.bind(this);
this.onSelectionChanged = this.onSelectionChanged.bind(this);
this.onCellClicked = this.onCellClicked.bind(this);
this.search = this.search.bind(this);
this.sellerDetailsAction = this.sellerDetailsAction.bind(this);
this.retrieveComplaints = this.retrieveComplaints.bind(this);
this.closeOverlay = this.closeOverlay.bind(this);
this.closeSearchBar = this.closeSearchBar.bind(this);
this.retrieveStateActions = this.retrieveStateActions.bind(this);
this.takeAction = this.takeAction.bind(this);
this.filterSubBrand = this.filterSubBrand.bind(this);

// Defining table columns - apparently this is the only option for now
this.columns = [
  { headerName: '', headerCellTemplate:CheckboxHeaderCell(() => this.api.selectAll(), () => this.api.deselectAll()), width: 50, checkboxSelection: true, suppressSorting: true, suppressResize: true, suppressMovable: true, onCellClicked: this.onCellClicked },
  { colId: 'url', headerName: 'Url', field: 'url', cellRendererFramework: LinkCell, onClick: this.showComplaintDetail, width: 250, sort: query && query.sortBy === "url" ? "asc" : "" },
  { colId: 'enforcementStatus', headerName: 'Enforcement Status', valueGetter: (params) => { return displayMapper.enforcement(params.data.enforcementStatus); } },
  { colId: 'createdDate', headerName: 'Date Created', valueGetter: (params) => { return moment(params.data.createdDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); }, sort: !query || (query && query.sortBy !== "url") ? "desc" : ""},
  { colId: 'submemberKey', headerName: 'Sub-Brand', valueGetter: (params) => { return displayMapper.subBrand(params.data.owner.subMemberKey); }, width: 150 },
  { colId: 'externalBatchId', headerName: 'IBID', valueGetter: (params) => { return params.data.complaintBatch ? params.data.complaintBatch.internalID : null; } },
  { colId: 'complaintIPR', headerName: 'IPR', valueGetter:(params) => { return displayMapper.ipr(params.data.ipr.iprType.code); } },
  { colId: 'platformCode', headerName: 'Platform', valueGetter:(params) => { return params.data.platform.name; } },
  { colId: 'complaintType', headerName: 'Complaint Type', valueGetter:(params) => { return displayMapper.complaint(params.data.complaintType.code); } },
  { headerName: 'SID', valueGetter: (params) => { return params.data.submissionBatch.internalID; } }
];
if (isAllowed('complaints.field.process')) this.columns.splice(7, 0, { colId: 'processStatus', headerName: 'Process Status', valueGetter: (params) => { return displayMapper.process(params.data.processStatus); } });
if (isAllowed('complaints.field.brand')) this.columns.splice(1, 0, { colId: 'memberKey', headerName: 'Brand', valueGetter: (params) => { return displayMapper.brand(params.data.owner.memberKey); }, width: 150 });};
```

What is the best way to put this code into shape?

Comment: to begin with, instead of using the `this` keyword everywhere, you can assign `this` to a variable with a proper name. Say it is a `person` object, then if you can do `var person = this;` then you can change the code to  `this.x = this.x.bind(person)`. You can do this for all your `this` keywords with relevant `obj` name thereby avoiding confusion.

Comment: move most of the code in utils/ functions such as `this.columns = createColumns(...args)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to bind your functions.  Using ES6 anonymous functions may be the most convenient way to refactor this.  This assumes you are using the `extends` syntax.

Basically, you can zap all those bindings in the constructor and re-write the functions.  I think this would be easier than binding them in the event handler?  Seems like you might be more prone to miss some that way.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this); // the React Component instance
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}></div>
    );
  }
}
```